# ¿Cómo filtrar un Data Frame por un vector de números?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo un data frame con 4 variables, mes, año, código y precipitaciones. Necesito obtener el data frame de acuerdo a la variable código que no sean iguales a los siguiente valores.

`vector = c(87553, 87568, 87569, 87570, 87571, 87572, 87573, 87574, 87576, 87582, 87593, 87596)`

El data frame es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté realizar
`df.mensual <- df.mensual %>% filter(codigo != vector)`

Pero obtuve el siguiente error
 `In codigo != vector : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador == o != trabaja solo para valores únicos y en tu caso intentas filtrar un vector, la solución es usar el %in%

```
df.mensual <- df.mensual %>% filter(!codigo %in% vector)
```

Le agregamos el ! (negación) para indicar que filtre los valores que no estan contenidos en el vector

Comment: Es correcta tu solución pero `"El operador == o != trabaja solo para valores únicos"`, es incorrecto, la igualdad funciona con vectores de múltiples valores. Saludos.

Comment: Toda la razón, ya que cuando el vector es múltiplo se recicla, gracias por aclararlo, saludos!